# Using Bing Image API in Jave to search for images

Tags: bing-api

I found this sample code at this [link](https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56b43f0ccf5ff8098cef3808/operations/571fab09dbe2d933e891028f)
I replace `{subscription key}` by my key but the result is always:

```
{ "statusCode": 404, "message": "Resource not found" }
```

I'm confused with this line:

```
StringEntity reqEntity = new StringEntity("{body}");
```

What should I replace `"{body}"` by ? 
Full code in the example from https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com is below

```
// // This sample uses the Apache HTTP client from HTTP Components (http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)
import java.net.URI;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class JavaSample 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

        try
        {
            URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder("https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/images/search");

            builder.setParameter("q", "cats");

            URI uri = builder.build();
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(uri);
            request.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
            request.setHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "{subscription key}");


            // Request body
            StringEntity reqEntity = new StringEntity("{body}");
            request.setEntity(reqEntity);

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) 
            {
                System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue here is the wrong method. For images/search endpoint, http method should be **GET** and not POST. POST method has a different endpoint for images API - to get insights.

All endpoints are here: https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/8336afba49a84475ba401758c0dbf749/operations/56b4433fcf5ff8098cef380c.